# How can I subtract the components of these 2 solutions if the components are interpolating functions?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, vector, distance

I have solved for solutions of the Lorentz system but for some reason Mathematica spit out `InterpolatingFunction[]` as components.

**Input 1:**

```
eqns = {x'[t] == 10 (y[t] - x[t]), 
   y'[t] == 28 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
   z'[t] == (-8/3) z[t] + x[t] y[t]};

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqns, x[0] == 10, y[0] == -10, z[0] == 25}, {x, y, 
    z}, {t, 0, 30}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

**Output 1:**
[image]

**Input 2:**

```
eqns2 = {x'[t] == 10 (y[t] - x[t]), 
   y'[t] == 28.0001 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
   z'[t] == (-8/3) z[t] + x[t] y[t]};

sol2 = NDSolve[{eqns2, x[0] == 10, y[0] == -10, z[0] == 25}, {x, y, 
   z}, {t, 0, 30}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
```

**Output 2:**

[image]

I need to find the Euclidean distance of the 2 solutions given by (for some time $t$):

$$d(t) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$

How can I do this with this output though?

Comment: "...for some reason Mathematica spit out InterpolatingFunction[] as components." As stated in the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) documentation, "NDSolve gives results in terms of InterpolatingFunction objects."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**compacted notation by Bob Hanlon**

```
f[t_] := EuclideanDistance@@({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /.{sol1, sol2})
```

**original attempt**

```
f[t_] := EuclideanDistance[({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. 
 sol1[[1]]), ({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol2[[1]])]

f[3]
(* 0.00631062 *)
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly more compact is `f[t_] = EuclideanDistance @@ ({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. {sol1, sol2});`

Comment: @BobHanlon putting your implementation as an edit with credits. Thanks !